# Populate Parent lookup pre-populated in Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have overridden the `New` action for a custom object which will take me to a Visualforce. It works well until there. So now my custom object has a lookup relationship to `Account`. So when trying to create/add a new custom object from the `Account` record I want a field in my Visualforce to be filled with the Account Name of that record.

This is what I tried - 
`<apex:outputText id="name" value="Name of the Customer/Business: {!escalation.Account__r.Name}"/>`

Comment: What exactly is the result?

Comment: so that output text should populate the Account name on the VisualForce page since the custom object in this case is being created from the Account record level.

Comment: That is the *expected* result. What is the *actual* result?

Comment: it doesn't show anything. Blank ..

Comment: Sanjay - is escalation the name of your custom object(which will make the api name escalation__c)?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do this myself here is what I did,
Visualforce-    `<apex:pageblocksectionitem>
                <apex:outputlabel value="Account Name"/>
                <apex:outputtext id="name" value="{!accname}" />
                </apex:pageblocksectionItem>`

Apex-

```
public string accname{get;set;}   
    public EscalationController(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
    accname=apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('CF00NR0000001UuHR');
    }
```

CF00NR0000001UuHR was copied from the URL(On clicking new button from Account record level)

Comment: Sanjay - I was just about to post a similar solution to what you just posted. When you click the new escalation button on the account related list the URL gives you two ids - one for the name of the account (starting with CF and the other for the Id of the account(starting with CF and ending with _lkid). I am glad you figured it out yourself. Kudos and +1.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is likely that `escalation.Account__r` is not defined in this context. If you have the Id, you will want to query for the `Account` in order to display it. Making some assumptions about your structure, the below should work.

**Extension**

```
public with sharing class MyExtension
{
    public Account parentAccount { get; private set; }
    public MyExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        Id accountId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters.get('accountId');
        parentAccount = [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Id = :accountId];
    }
}
```

**Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="My_Object__c" extensions="MyExtension">
    <apex:outputText value="{!parentAccount.Name}" />
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I'm receiving this error - 'List has no rows for assignment to SObject '